# rich:popupPanel submits value on .hide() , which i dont want

Tags: ckeditor, richfaces, submit

I'm having trouble with canceling the changes done with CKeditor in richfaces 4.

In short:

```
<form>
  ...
  <rich:popupPanel>
     <rich:editor id="#{popupID}" value="#{managedBean.value}" />
     <a4j:commandButton value="Annuleer" onclick="#{rich:component(popupID)}.hide();" />
     <a4j:commandButton value="Ok" onclick="saveEditorData();" />
  </rich:popupPanel>
  ...
</form>
```

When i press the [Cancel] ("Annuleer") button, it closes the popuppanel and 'submits' the value to the bean. When pressing [Cancel] I dont want it to submit the value. I have the feeling I am missing something very simple yet crucial to make this work.

How can i make the [Cancel] Button work as intended?

The full code:

```
<rich:popupPanel
 id="#{popupID}"
 modal="true"
 autosized="true"
 resizeable="false"
 styleClass="popup-panel"
 style="z-index:202;"
 left="300"
 domElementAttachment="parent">
 <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Text Editor " />
 </f:facet>
 <f:facet name="controls">
    <a4j:commandButton
    value="X"
    type="reset"
    id="popupAfsluiten"
    render="#{panelID}"
    styleClass="btn-afsl"
    onclick="showLoadingOverlay();#{rich:component(popupID)}.hide();"
    oncomplete="cleanOverlay();setFocus('#{rich:clientId(inputID)}');return false;"/>
 </f:facet>
 <rich:panel id="#{cc.attrs.id}TextPanel">
     <rich:editor id="textEditor" lang="nl" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.formField(cc.attrs.id).value}" toolbar="CustomToolbar">
        <f:facet name="config">
            toolbar_CustomToolbar:
                [
                    { name: 'document', items: [ 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print'] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','PasteText','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
                    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
                    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize' ] }
                ],
            language: 'nl',
            defaultLanguage : 'nl',
            scayt_sLang : 'nl_NL',
            startupFocus: true,
            pasteFromWordPromptCleanup : true,
            pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles : true,
            forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
            ignoreEmptyParagraph : true,
            removeFormatAttributes : true,
            removePlugins : 'elementspath',
            tabSpaces : 4,
            autoParagraph : false,
            autoUpdateElement : false,
            enterMode: Number(2)
        </f:facet>
    </rich:editor>
    <a4j:commandButton
    value="Annuleer"
    type="reset"
    id="editorCancel"
    render="#{panelID}"
    styleClass="btn-ja"
    onclick="showLoadingOverlay();#{rich:component(popupID)}.hide();"
    oncomplete="cleanOverlay();setFocus('#{rich:clientId(inputID)}');return false;"/>

    <a4j:commandButton
        value="Ok"
        type="submit"
        styleClass="btn-ja"
        id="#{inputID}Save"
        render="#{inputID}"
        onclick="saveEditorData();"
        oncomplete="setTime();" />
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="Opgeslagen om: " />
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{editorBean.value}" id="saveTimeOutput"/>
     </rich:panel>
  </rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is being submitted by a4j:commandButton.

If you are using richfaces 3.3.3 then add attribute ajaxSingle = true like this

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Annuleer" ajaxSingle="true"  
                     onclick="#{rich:component(popupID)}.hide();" />
```

If you are using richfaces 4.X then use execute attribute

```
 <a4j:commandButton value="Annuleer" execute="@this"  
                   onclick="#    {rich:component(popupID)}.hide();" />
```

In both the cases only your command button is processed in the backend.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To cancel the request to server altogether, add `return false;` to the onclick handler:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Annuleer"
        onclick="#{rich:component(popupID)}.hide(); return false" />
```

If you still need to re-render some area (so you need the ajax request), then use the solution stated in other answers (`execute="@this"`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not the popupPanel that does that. `<a4j:commandButton>` and `commandLink` submit the whole form by default. If you don't want to submit anything add `execute="@none"`.

Comment: I believe it should be execute="@this". "@none" will process nothing

Comment: both execute="@none" and execute="@this" work. Is there any difference between those 2?

Comment: @SrikanthGanji there is nothing to process though. The button has no `@actionListener` that would need to be executed.